# Buddypress for wordpress activity filter options

Tags: wordpress, android-activity, filtering, buddypress

I have asked several questions on the buddypress forum but I never get any sort of response or help.  I seem to always get a valid well thought out answer on the stackoverflow community, so I am posting my question here too. Here is my original post to the buddypress forum that no one has answered. Seems like a good question that some dev could answer easily.  maybe someone here has some experience or guidance and can point me in the right direction.

Hey, i was wondering I found this webpage http://codex.buddypress.org/developer-docs/custom-buddypress-loops/the-activity-stream-loop/ on editing the activity stream loop with some information on filtering the main activity wall but I am really still confused because It doesn’t seem like all the available options are listed here. For example right under it it says if ( bp_has_activities( ‘type=status’) ) :

Well ‘type=status’ is no where listed on this page and I know there are several other options available that are also not listed. So my question is what and where can I find all the available options for filtering. I am setting up some custom options for my site and I would love some help. I am familiar with php so if there is a file i can look at then I would love to know about it too.

Please Advise Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the filters and accepted parameters are on the [page you referenced](http://codex.buddypress.org/developer-docs/custom-buddypress-loops/the-activity-stream-loop/) (just scroll down it a little bit). For some reason in the example they use `type=status` when it should be `object=status` as that is the correct way to filter for status updates only.

You can always take a look [at the actual function itself](http://phpxref.ftwr.co.uk/buddypress/nav.html?_functions/index.html) to see accepted parameters. Buddypress is much better documented in the code than on their website.